# как добавить 'VK_ios_sdk' в проект swift

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api

с помощью cocoapods добавил VK_ios_sdk

[image: скрин]

но проект не видит библиотеку:

No such module 'VK_ios_sdk'

Просьба помочь, дать совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте [`briging header`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) и добавьте

```
#import "VKSdk.h"
```

и все будет видно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! разобрался, за работало!